# get correct PID of internet explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-11, pid

I need to get the correct PID of internet explorer.
By starting the IE there exist two processes. I need to get the one I get via taskmanager from the running applicationv view (right click on mouse of the IE symbol -> change to process). I don't know how to get this pid via c#. I get an array of the two pids, but I don't know how to get the correct one automaticlly as describen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look at this, there seems to be a 32-bit and a 64-bit IE process running.

If you use "go to process" in the task manager with IE, it takes you to the 64-bit process.

See if you can filter these processes by 32 vs 64 bit.